# LaTeX Sublime Text Equation Preview

Tags: equations, preview

I recently installed Sublime Text 3 and am attempting to produce a pdf document with some complex math. However, my equation previewer is not functioning correctly for math environments. When I change my math scope to “text.tex.latex meta.environment.math”, the following appears:
[image: Error]
And when my scope is changed to “text.tex.latex meta.environment.math,block”, I see the same but without any previews for the math enclosed in $$.
In both scenarios, there is no preview for the equations I have in the multline* environment and in the regular equation environment ( [ … ] ). Any suggestions for what my problem might be?

Note: I have sent the .tex file to a sublime text iOS user and they were able to see all the appropriate equations without issue.